# How to run and stop a delayed_jobs worker in a Thread or Subprocess for testing purposes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, multithreading, testing, delayed-job

I would like to be able to perform some tests that require a worker to be running.

In order to accomplish this created this test helper method:

```
def with_delayed_jobs
  t=Thread.new {Delayed::Worker.new.start}
  sleep(5)
  yield
  t.exit
end
```

So I can write in my tests

```
with_delayed_jobs {
  ___test_content___
}
```

Unfortunately, the worker doesn't seem to run this way. Maybe I can do it  with processes. Does anybody have an idea on how to accomplish this?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish with `@method_ran`. Do you have jobs queued in your jobs table?

Comment: Forget about it. I was making a mess with class/instance variables in order to test this thing. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run the jobs that are currently in your jobs table with this:

```
 Delayed::Worker.new(
          :max_priority => nil,
          :min_priority => nil,
          :quiet => true
        ).work_off
```

[Docs are here, although they are sparse.](http://rubydoc.info/gems/delayed_job/2.0.5/Delayed/Worker#work_off-instance_method)

Comment: This runs the jobs that are already in your queue. I'm not sure what your edit is trying to show.

Comment: Thanks! Just what I was looking for! I needed this to execute the worker immediately after scheduling a job at a predefined time. Then the worker will run and shut itself down after the job is done. Nice.